# Liquibase- generate changelogFile for existing database

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to use liquibase for generating the changeLog, but when I run this in a terminal

```
> liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=./db.changelog-1.0.0.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/recproject_test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding
=UTF-8" --username=<username>--password=<password> generateChangeLog
```

I get communicat:

'liquibase' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I added liquibase to my pom.xml as a dependency and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I used liquibase.bat, but I received

> Command not passed

I runed command like below

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile="C:/Users/user/Desktop/SampleProject/web/src/main/resources/data/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.0.xml" --url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/recproject_test?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" --username=user --password=root
```

Comment: This may help you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449824/liquibase-how-to-generate-a-changelog-for-existing-database

Comment: You can run/start liquibase either via maven or on the commandline/terminal. On the terminal there is a `liquibase.bat` file to start it on Windows. And on Linux/Mac there is bash script `liquibase` that will start it. Maybe you need to set it to executable using `chmod` when you are on linux/mac?

Comment: .bat sounds like you are on windows, so please don't forget to add the liquibase folder to the PATH environment variable and restart the cmd.